# How to perform case-insensitive search in MarkLogic KeyValueQueryDefintion?

Tags: marklogic

The following MarkLogic search is doing a case-sensitive search? How to perform a case-insensitive search using the following code snippet?

```
String optionsName = "PRODUCT_BY_TITLE";
String options ="&lt;search:options xmlns:search='http://marklogic.com/appservices/search'>"+         "&lt;/search:options>";

QueryOptionsManager qoManager = 
    client.newServerConfigManager().newQueryOptionsManager();
// create a handle to send the query options
StringHandle writeHandle = new StringHandle(options);
// write the query options to the database
qoManager.writeOptions(optionsName, writeHandle);

QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
KeyValueQueryDefinition kvqdef = queryMgr.newKeyValueDefinition(optionsName);
kvqdef.put(queryMgr.newElementLocator(new QName(ConstantsUtil.BIBLIOGRAPHIC_MSG_NAMESPACE_PREFIX+":"+elementName)), elementValue);              
JacksonHandle handle = new JacksonHandle();
queryMgr.search(kvqdef, handle);                
logger.info("response-->"+handle.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Andy:

KeyValueQueryDefinition is intended for the simplest cases.  Your requirements have graduated to a more sophisticated interface.

You can use StructuredQueryBuilder to pass in options for your element values query:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html

Something along the lines of the following code (untested) should work:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder(optionsName);
StructuredQueryDefinition queryDef = qb.value(
    qb.element(new QName(
        ConstantsUtil.BIBLIOGRAPHIC_MSG_NAMESPACE_PREFIX+":"+elementName)),
    FragmentScope.DOCUMENTS,
    new String[]{"case-insensitive"},
    1,
    elementValue);
JacksonHandle handle = new JacksonHandle();
queryMgr.search(queryDef, handle);
```

Hoping that helps

Comment: I am getting an error: com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: search failed: Bad Request. Server Message: REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Invalid parameter: Invalid query structure (check namespace): <query xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><value-query><element ns="" name="TitleText"/><fragment-scope>documents</fragment-scope><text>Collins Gem Polish Dictionary</text><term-option>case-insensitive</term-option><weight>1.0</weight></value-query></query>